# Is there any meaning to call pthread_detach(th) after calling pthread_join(th,NULL) ?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I found a piece of strange code in a open source software

```
for (i=0; i<store->scan_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL);
    pthread_detach(thread_ids[i]);
}
```

Is there any meaning to call pthread_detach ?

Comment: What does `pthread_detach()` return? 0 or error number?

Answer (score 3):

That stanza is silly and unsafe.

Design-wise, the `detach` is unnecessary — the `join` completion already means that the thread is completely finished.  There's nothing to detach.  (The code in question simply spawns threads with default joinability.)

Implementation-wise, the `detach` is unsafe.  A thread ID may be recycled as soon as the thread is finished — oops, didn't mean to detach that other thread!  Worse, the ID is not guaranteed to be meaningful at all after the call to `join` returns — SEGV?

Comment: I doubt detaching an already join thread will segfault, but just return `ESRCH`. But the race, resulting in probably detaching another thread is the **real** dangerous issue here: 1+

Comment: @alk, I expect you're right in practice.  (On my platform, I think `pthread_t` is an `unsigned long`, FWIW.)  However, my understanding of strict spec conformance is that the thread identifier of a wholly completed thread (terminated+joined or detached+terminated) must be regarded as *de facto* uninitialized.  Probably ESRCH, but possibly, just possibly, monkeys flying out of your nose.

Comment: Looking up the latest POSIX specs I see that `ESRCH` as well as `EINVAL` had been removed as possible result for `pthread_detach()`. Accepting unjoinable or invalid thread-ids is a "may" requirement now: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html

Answer (score 1):

In this code (considering that this code is from main thread.... )

```
pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL);
```

this will wait the main thread to return thread with thread id "thread_ids[i]", and if main thread is doing some more work then

```
pthread_detach(thread_ids[i]);
```

will release the resource used by the thread (with thread id "thread_ids[i]).